# Assigning value from setState to a variable in React js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, setstate

In the middle of a slightly long component which is basically a split date input (3 inputs for DD/MM/YYYY) - I think my approach is correct for the most part, but I'm struggling with my `getDate` function. The idea is that the `currentDate` is passed into this function (whatever has been entered in the keyboard), like so:

```
  const handleValueChange = (date?: string) => {
    onValueChange(getDate(date));
  };
```

In the `getDate` function I want to take the values from `selectedDay`, `selectedMonth` & `selectedYear` and assign them to variables so that they can then be joined using the `.join` method and a valid date like "28-08-2022" can be returned.

Can anyone advise on a best possible approach?

```
const getDate = (date?: string): string => {
  if (date) {
    /* need to take value for DD/ MM / YYYY and store them in 
    individual variables that can then be used in an array or 
    something similar with .join to return a 
    joined up date like "28-09-2022" */
  }

  return "";
};

const DateInput = ({
  dateInputValue,
  dateInputFormat,
  className,
  inFilterContext,
  onChange,
  onValueChange,
  value = "",
  type = "text",
  readOnly = false,
  disabled = false,
  placeholder,
  mindate,
  maxdate,
  ...inputProps
}: Props) => {
  const [intialDayValue, initialMonthValue, initialYearValue] =
    dateInputValue.split("-");
  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(intialDayValue || "");
  const [selectedMonth, setSelectedMonth] = useState(initialMonthValue || "");
  const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState(initialYearValue || "");

  const handleValueChange = (date?: string) => {
    onValueChange(getDate(date));
  };

  // handle date input change event - DAY
  const handleDayChangeEvent = (e: SyntheticInputEvent<any>) => {
    const currentDate = e.target.value;

    setSelectedDay(currentDate);
    handleValueChange(currentDate);
  };

  // handle date input change event - MONTH
  const handleMonthChangeEvent = (e: SyntheticInputEvent<any>) => {
    const currentDate = e.target.value;

    setSelectedMonth(currentDate);
    handleValueChange(currentDate);
  };

  // handle date input change event - YEAR
  const handleYearChangeEvent = (e: SyntheticInputEvent<any>) => {
    const currentDate = e.target.value;

    setSelectedYear(currentDate);
    handleValueChange(currentDate);
  };

  return (
    <StyledInputGroup>
      <label htmlFor={`${name}_day`}>
        <span>Day</span>
        <StyledInput
          {...inputProps}
          type={type}
          maxLength="2"
          disabled={disabled}
          readOnly={readOnly}
          value={selectedDay}
          onChange={handleDayChangeEvent}
          onValueChange={handleDateSelectDay}
        />
      </label>
      <label htmlFor={`${name}_month`}>
        <span>Month</span>
        <StyledInput
          {...inputProps}
          type={type}
          maxLength="2"
          disabled={disabled}
          readOnly={readOnly}
          value={selectedMonth}
          onChange={handleMonthChangeEvent}
          onValueChange={handleDateSelectMonth}
        />
      </label>
      <label htmlFor={`${name}_year`}>
        <span>Year</span>
        <StyledInput
          {...inputProps}
          type={type}
          maxLength="4"
          disabled={disabled}
          readOnly={readOnly}
          value={selectedYear}
          onChange={handleYearChangeEvent}
        />
      </label>
    </StyledInputGroup>
  );
```